# Overriding ETag lookups?

Tags: django, apache, http, etag

**I would like to override Etag lookups, because apparently they are slowing down a page as the latency for each request is quite BIG!**

Expires headers don't seem to do the trick...

any ideas?

Comment: How do you figure it's the fault of ETags?

Comment: I don't know why it is still making the lookups... I have given all files Expires Headers!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

In the response object from the view you can set the `ETag` to whatever you like. This requires that you are using `CommonMiddleware` and `USE_ETAGS` is set to `True`.

However, if what you really want to do is to not call the view at all, why don't you just use the cache decorators and cache the result?

[The code for etag handling.](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/common.py#L112)

Answer (score 0):

I wish people would ask questions stating the version of apache they are running.  This can get confusing quite quickly.  Look at the FileETag directive (at least for apache 2.0 and 2.2).

FileETag none // will not generate and ETag for a file

See [FileETag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#fileetag)

Comment: There is nothing implying he's using apache.

Comment: Except that he tagged it Apache :P

Answer (score 0):

> each request is quite BIG!

Unless you've got some really funky custom patches on your apache installation or a very weird filesystem, the effort of generating an eTAG is not dependent on the size of the file - by default Apache uses the inode number, mod time and size.

Usually conditional requests can actually slow down a site a lot - and should be avoided (preferable by stripping the if-none-match / if-modified-since request header). The one time this is not the case is where you publish very large files (e.g. video, PDFs). If you can't modify the request headers (e.g. using Apache<2.0), then you'd need to strip both the ETag and the last-modified from the response - or refresh the timestamps opn your files regularly.

The 'Expires' header is an HTTP/1.0 directive - there's very little HTTP/1.0 traffic going on out there - the little which is usually comes from badly configured MSIE6 browsers working through a proxy). You should be sending out Cache-Control headers.